# approach to reports with knitr including R codes with (very) long execution time

Tags: r, knitr

I'm writing at the moment a report including  R codes with long execution time. I use knitr for this purpose. (as presented in http://yihui.name/knitr/options/ )

As pointed out of this website, one should use the option "cache=TRUE" for implementing the codes in the report, because it reduces the computation time for compilling the file after the first compiling.

> The problem is now if one changes the code slightly, which is often done during editing/debugging or learning/playing commands, it does not use cache and
>   computes it again with long execution time. Therefore, it is a bit tedious to work.
>
> Is there a way to overcome the above problem?

Comment: separate out the code into more discrete, cache-able chunks and try to not have them dependent on each other.

Comment: Put the slow code into a separate R script that saves its output at the end.  Have your document just read the saved output.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions, I appreciate it. It seems that working with such codes need a more careful treat, because there is no "general" solution in the sense of a suitable command or anything like that. Is that correct? In this case you can write your comment as answers and will clear this question.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Rethinking about this situation, you can write your comment as an answer and I will accept it as an answer of this question.